# What are the views on sexuality in Warhammer?

Tags: lore, wfrp-2e

Are there any canonical statements about the views of various races, societies, and factions in Warhammer on the subject of sexuality? For examples,

- Does Imperial law have an opinion on homosexuality?

  - For example, would an accusation of homosexuality by Sigmarite zealots make sense as a plot point? (i.e. would that be seen as negative, would the zealots use that as an attack?)
- Are dwarfs sexual at all? How?
- What are common taboos around humans and elves?

Slaanesh cult does not count!

Comment: I see nothing about this lore question that is a matter of opinion, so I've reopened it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Possibilities

"Is it possible..." to have characters "called out" for homosexuality in WFRP? Sure. But is there any canon on this? No. Sigmarite or other.

### Imperial Law

Imperial "law" in as much as it is canonized, to my knowledge, does not present a position on sexuality or sexual preference.

### Slaanesh

Sorry, but Sigmarites are going to see sympathies for Slaanesh, as debauched by the Ruinous Powers, before they likely consider "homosexuality." I believe Slaanesh (or Tzeench) will play into any accusation, but I do not think for the specific "accusation" of homosexuality. Instead, a Sigmarite might see such a character as indulging in an excess of carnal pleasure, regardless of homosexual or heterosexual encounters, and thus corrupted by Slaanesh (or Tzeentch). Sure "moral corruption" is a possibility, but you create in-game canon at that point.

### Game of City-States

*Game of Thrones* features a story line of the [Faith of the Seven zealots](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Faith_of_the_Seven) disapproving of homosexuality. If you really want to seed something more sinister, consider reading or watching the series.

### Demi-humans

Are Dwarfs and Elves sexually active? Sure. Is it canonized? Not really. And no "proper extension" has ever been published. Elves can be hedonistic. Take that for what it's worth. There are no "half-elves" canonized. I just had two players, a human male and an elven female bathe together while having two other characters walk in to the bath and carry on complete conversations. It was funny and the specifics of the human/elf encounter was never discussed at the table.

### Conclusion

If you're just looking for provocative session play for characters, I would stick to the excesses of pleasure angle and invoke corruption by Slaanesh or Tzeentch. Consider that half-elves would be considered a mutation by most (besides not being canonized).

Last, your question almost suggests that you want something more sexual in your game. WFRP might not be the game or setting for you.

And remember you can push boundaries too far and players can "vote with their feet."

Answer (score 8):

## Let's look at the edition prior...

#### Non-heteronormative sexuality

*Middenheim: City of the White Wolf* (1e) gives the basic overview of the legal system of the Empire. It doesn't specifically call out sexual offenses, but does call out blasphemy and heresy.

We know that the Slaneeshi cult is both proscribed and embraces lechery, debauchery, bondage, fetishism, and pansexuality (sex acts with anything).

The insanities do not include Homosexuality nor homophobia, but do include gynophobia and androphobia, but not one's own gender. Likewise, hatred of the opposite gender is an insanity.

The only homosexual characters I recall are all chaos worshipers.

#### Non-Human Norms

We know that, of the 5 PC races in 1E, all 4 core (Human, Elf, Dwarf, Halfling) have males and females, marriage, and similar family sizes. It is noted in Tome of Corruption that mutant children of the non-Human are quickly destroyed.

How? Because of the 1E character pack. It gives expanded character background, specifies the genders, and does not provide for "adopted into non-heteronormative family."

All the family specified is 1 man, 1 woman, and their children, with the potential that one or both parents are no longer alive.

## And On To Second Ed...

#### Laws and Trials

The legal system is explained in *Sigmar's Heirs*, with advanced trial rules in the *WFRP Companion*.

#### Gender

The corebook still specifies all 4 core races have both male and female members, there are gender differences in naming (page 27, example names on the tables).

We also see in the description of Slaneesh that Slaneesh is, itself, hermaphroditic and bisexual, with implications of pansexual and sado-masochistic tendencies. Like 1E, however, homosexuality isn't in the insanities.

We do not have the family generation in 2E - thus we can say less about what is normal.

## Societal Depiction

The society within the setting is a caricature of the late medieval and early renaissance period. A period of high superstition, and many religious persecutions and intolerances. Conformity is imposed, enforced often by the extremes of execution and maiming.

## A Note on the Meaning of Sexual & Gender

Sexual, as a technical term, has a scientific meaning of reproducing by mixing genetic material from two parents, to create the offspring.

Gender has, in stable terms, essentially 4 basic gender types: Male, Female, Hermaphrodite, other intersex, and Neuter.

Females generate the egg cell, and either deliver the egg or the resultant child. In mammalian forms, this is always after fertilization by sperm.

Males generate the sperm cells, and deliver them to the egg, either before or after it's delivered. In mammalian forms, this is always before delivery.

Hermaphrodites have both male and female reproductive systems. In most cases, arranged such that an individual is not capable of self-impregnating. No mamalian species is normally hermaphroditic, while some molluscs and worms are.

Neuter individuals lack either gender... and in mammalian forms, are sterile.

All the races shown are shown to have two biological genders: male and female. Thus, all the races are implied strongly to have male-female sexual reproduction.

Certain non-mammalian forms have sequential gender - male at one range of ages, female at other age ranges.

A few species have only one gender as normative, female, and reproduce asexually, but those are fish or lizards.

This leads to answering the sub-question of Dwarven sexuality as "male-female intercourse appears to be the norm."

Given the association with Slaneesh, a herm child would likely be culled in Elf or Dwarf society, and quite possibly  mutilated into an apparent female in Human and/or Halfling society, if allowed to live. Hermaphrodites are not included on the mutations tables, nor on the gender tables, nor in the 1E family tables, so none of the races covered have a significant rate of hermaphroditism.

Reality, however, is far messier with gender in mammals - the tiny fraction of individuals who are neither fully male nor fully female biologically are a spectrum, with a rare few fully functional herms, and a variety of non-reproductive herms, ambiguous genitalia, and such. Intersex, including true herms, are about 1:1500 to 1:2000 in the general population. [cite](http://healthresearchfunding.org/15-notable-ambiguous-genitalia-statistics/)

#### Gender and the Game

We can assume that this hold to its relatively standard rates of about 1 per 1500 or fewer individuals expressing intersex, and isn't included on the tables simply due to granularity.

Or, we can assume that intersex individuals would be culled, and the parents probably neutered  and/or burned at the stake by a paranoid and fearful population. The charge would be Worship of Slaneesh, and the deformation of the intersex child would be more than plenty proof for most witch hunters.

We have no reason to assume any of the core races to be outside the two gender paradigm (with potential under 1% deviation), normal male-female procreative copulation and all individuals having one biologic male parent and one biologic female parent, and having been gestated within.

We do know, however, that not all intelligent races in the Warhammer world follow this. The corebook races, however, are pretty much demi-humans, and not really outside human norms.

## General conclusions

Sexuality amongst the corebook races is apparently pretty heteronormative.

The game avoids labeling homosexuality  neither as proscribed, criminal, nor insanity, nor as an aspect of Slaneesh. It does subtlety imply this, however.

The intolerant society would most likely be rabidly heteronormative, as was historical early renaissance Germany - which the Empire is a parody of.